# Instance of a typeclass in two different ways

Tags: haskell

I would have liked to create two instances of an associated type family, like so. This won't compile, of course, and I ended up taking a different approach in my code. However, I'm still curious about this use case. I think that *in theory* it would be possible for the compiler to allow this. Even though there would be multiple instances of `put` and `get` to choose from, the result type makes it clear which instance is required.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
import Data.Word

class Genetic g where
  type Sequence g :: *
  -- | Writes a gene to a sequence.
  put :: Sequence g -> g -> Sequence g
  -- | Reads the next gene in a sequence.
  get :: Sequence g -> (g, Sequence g)

data SampleGene = Variant1 | Variant2 deriving Show

instance Genetic SampleGene where
  type Sequence SampleGene = [Bool]
  put xs Variant1 = True : xs
  put xs Variant2 = False : xs
  get (True:xs) = (Variant1, xs)
  get (False:xs) = (Variant2, xs)

instance Genetic SampleGene where
  type Sequence SampleGene = [Word8]
  put xs Variant1 = 0 : xs
  put xs Variant2 = 1 : xs
  get (0:xs) = (Variant1, xs)
  get (1:xs) = (Variant2, xs)
  get _ = error "coding error"

main = do
  putStrLn "Working with Bool sequences"
  let xs = put [] Variant1 :: [Bool]
  let (g,ys) = get xs :: (SampleGene, [Bool])
  putStrLn $ "Read " ++ show g
  putStrLn "Working with Bool sequences"
  let xs = put [] Variant1 :: [Word8]
  let (g,ys) = get xs :: (SampleGene, [Word8])
  putStrLn $ "Read " ++ show g
```

My questions are:

1. Is there any way to do this in Haskell? (Apart from newtype wrappers - I want users of my library to be able to use Haskell base types directly.)
2. If not, why not? I.e., what rule am I violating, or what limitation of the type system am I hitting? I want to explain this in a paper I'm writing, but I'm trying to learn about how the type system works under the hood. So if you use technical terminology in your answer, then I can be on the lookout for those terms in my reading.
3. *In theory*, would it be possible for a future Haskell extension to allow this, or is it a non-starter?

I have seen [In Haskell, is there any way to express that a type should be an instance of a typeclass in more than one way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998732/in-haskell-is-there-any-way-to-express-that-a-type-should-be-an-instance-of-a-t), which is very similar to my question. However, my focus is on trying to better understand the type system.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think even with type families you're going to need to use newtypes, which is primarily what the `newtype` semantics are for, the other use being that you can make types more obvious, such as using `Network.Socket.PortNumber` instead of just `Word16`, making the type signature far more clear as to what is needed for that argument.

Comment: Have you tried adding the type of the `Sequence` as a second parameter to the class?

Comment: @Joachim I hadn't tried multi-parameter type class. The trend seems to be to use type families instead, but maybe this is a case where an MPTC can do something that a type family can't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type families are a bit weaker than MPTCs in that they express mere functions of types instead of full relations. This has advantages for type inference and is the reason MPTCs have fundeps as well. So, I don't think it'd be impossible to implement something like this, but its instead falling on the wrong side of a typechecker power/weight ratio.

In any case, if you genuinely want this behavior it's easy enough to have via MPTCs

```
class Genetic s g where
  -- | Writes a gene to a sequence.
  put :: s -> g -> s
  -- | Reads the next gene in a sequence.
  get :: s -> (g, s)

instance Genetic [Bool] SampleGene where
  put xs Variant1 = True  : xs
  put xs Variant2 = False : xs
  get (True  : xs) = (Variant1, xs)
  get (False : xs) = (Variant2, xs)

instance Genetic [Int] SampleGene where
  put xs Variant1 = 0 : xs
  put xs Variant2 = 1 : xs
  get (0 : xs) = (Variant1, xs)
  get (1 : xs) = (Variant2, xs)
  get _        = error "boo"
```